# Error doing Graph tutorial - ArgumentNullException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am getting this error: ArgumentNullException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.

While trying to link Microsoft Graph using their tutorial, the tutorial is in .NET 5, my project was already started on .NET 6.

I've tried a few solutions from stack but nothing seemed to work, i've removed my client id and tenantid for this question.

Program.cs

```
using Dotnet.Graph;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using DotNetify;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
            var graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(
                new Microsoft.Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                {
                    var token = await tokenAcquisition
                        .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, user: context.Principal);
                    request.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                }));

            var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .Select(u => new
                {
                    u.DisplayName,
                    u.Mail,
                    u.UserPrincipalName,
                    u.MailboxSettings
                })
                .GetAsync();

            context.Principal.AddUserGraphInfo(user);

            // Get the user's photo
            // If the user doesn't have a photo, this throws
            try
            {
                var photo = await graphClient.Me
                    .Photos["48x48"]
                    .Content
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

                context.Principal.AddUserGraphPhoto(photo);
            }
            catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException ex)
            {
                if (ex.IsMatch("ErrorItemNotFound") ||
                    ex.IsMatch("ConsumerPhotoIsNotSupported"))
                {
                    context.Principal.AddUserGraphPhoto(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        };

        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Exception.Message);
            context.Response
                .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Authentication+error&debug={error}");
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        };

        options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException)
            {
                var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Failure.Message);
                context.Response
                    .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Sign+in+error&debug={error}");
                context.HandleResponse();
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        };
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(GraphConstants.Scopes)
    //.AddDownstreamWebApi("CrmAuth", builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphBeta"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddDotNetify();


builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseDotNetify();

app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<DotNetifyHub>("/dotnetify"));

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.Run();
```

GraphConstants.cs

```
namespace Dotnet.Graph;

public static class GraphConstants
{
    // Defines the permission scopes used by the app
    public readonly static string[] Scopes =
    {
        "User.Read",
        "MailboxSettings.Read",
        "Calendars.ReadWrite"
    };
}
```

GraphClaimsPrincipalExtensions.cs

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Dotnet.Graph
{
    public static class GraphClaimTypes
    {
        public const string DisplayName = "graph_name";
        public const string Email = "graph_email";
        public const string Photo = "graph_photo";
        public const string TimeZone = "graph_timezone";
        public const string TimeFormat = "graph_timeformat";
    }

    // Helper methods to access Graph user data stored in
    // the claims principal
    public static class GraphClaimsPrincipalExtensions
    {
        public static string GetUserGraphDisplayName(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(GraphClaimTypes.DisplayName);
        }

        public static string GetUserGraphEmail(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(GraphClaimTypes.Email);
        }

        public static string GetUserGraphPhoto(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(GraphClaimTypes.Photo);
        }

        public static string GetUserGraphTimeZone(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(GraphClaimTypes.TimeZone);
        }

        public static string GetUserGraphTimeFormat(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(GraphClaimTypes.TimeFormat);
        }

        public static void AddUserGraphInfo(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, User user)
        {
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.DisplayName, user.DisplayName));
            identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.Email,
                    user.Mail ?? user.UserPrincipalName));
            identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.TimeZone,
                    user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone));
            identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.TimeFormat, user.MailboxSettings.TimeFormat));
        }

        public static void AddUserGraphPhoto(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, Stream photoStream)
        {
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            if (photoStream == null)
            {
                // Add the default profile photo
                identity.AddClaim(
                    new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.Photo, "/img/no-profile-photo.png"));
                return;
            }

            // Copy the photo stream to a memory stream
            // to get the bytes out of it
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            photoStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var photoBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            // Generate a date URI for the photo
            var photoUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes)}";

            identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.Photo, photoUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
  "TenantId": "tenantidremoved",
  "ClientId": "clientidremoved",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" : true
  },
```

Comment: This line in your Program.cs does nothing currently: `builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");`. I think you should bind the section to some options or assign it to a variable and set the settings from there.

Comment: Could you share link with the tutorial?

Comment: @juunas Could you point me in the right direction for doing that? Sorry I am new to Azure and working my way through tutorials to learn.

user2250152 This is the one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core

Comment: Here in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3 Implement Sign-in third step, around the middle they do a Configuration.Bind().

Comment: Thank you @juunas that worked great! Not sure how I missed it.